# Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server

Tags: dnsmasq

Unable to start dnsmasq on my raspberry pi 3b+ with stretch installed. Following is  the error.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# systemctl status dnsmasq.service  
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server  
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-10-05 04:45:09 IST; 8s ago  
  Process: 4609 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)  

Oct 05 04:45:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...   
Oct 05 04:45:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203  
Oct 05 04:45:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.  
Oct 05 04:45:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Unit entered failed state.  
Oct 05 04:45:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# dnsmasq  
bash: dnsmasq: command not found  
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test  
bash: /usr/sbin/dnsmasq: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have the `systemd` service unit for `dnsmasq`, but the executable is missing.

You don't mention what distribution you are using, but basically, you have to reinstall the `dnsmasq` executable. If you installed from source, install again. More likely, you used the package manager from your distribution. Probably the easiest is to save the `dnsmasq` configuration, uninstall and then install again. For Debian based systems you can use `apt`, for RPM use `yum`, for Suse use `zypper` or `yast`.

You should also try to find out how this could happen. Was there a time when `dnsmasq` worked? DO you remember deleting some files?

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: The easiest is uninstall and install `dnsmasq`.

Comment: I am using raspbian stretch. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling many times. I even manually removed the config directory after uninstalling. But i had no luck.

Comment: Anyways thanks for your help. I am able to get back the things to normal after running apt autoremove after purging dnsmasq before the reinstall.